# How to move pyautogui.prompt()?

Tags: python, pyautogui

When `pyautogui.prompt()` is called it displays a message box and it's always in the same spot. That box covers pictures I need to see, so I can write the right number. I need to move the box or make it invisible or minimize it or make it out of focus.

The problem is that you can't execute code while or after the message box is showing. The pyautogui.prompt is coded like this: `pyautogui.prompt(text='', title='', default='', root=None, timeout=None)`. I know what each argument does, ***except*** root. The root argument doesn't accept boolean, integers, lists, strings, Point or tuple. It displays an error message: `AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'withdraw'`, if you put boolean, integers, lists, strings, Point or tuple in.

The only thing that root accepts is `pyautogui.moveTo`, `pyautogui.dragTo` and other mouse commands. Which are not that useful, because they execute before the box appears. Here is my code:

```
import pyautogui

selected_picture = int(pyautogui.prompt('Please write which picture to click on.',
                                        'Select picture'))

if selected_picture == 1:
   pyautogui.click(500,270)
if selected_picture == 2:
    pyautogui.click(700,270)
if selected_picture == 3:
    pyautogui.click(900,270)
```

Yes, I need to do it with `pyautogui.prompt` or some other message box. The original documentation doesn't even mention the root or timeout attribute and I can't find that information anywhere. I was trying something with tkinter, but I have no idea what it does.

Comment: You may be able to set the `root` argument to an instance of a [`tk.Toplevel`](https://web.archive.org/web/20190429194251id_/http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/toplevel.html) (and called its `.geometry()` method to position it where you want before passing it to `pyautogui.prompt()`).

Comment: @martineau I tried to pass `tkinter.Tk().geometry()` to `root`. It displayed two windows. One window was from `prompt` and the other was from `tkinter`.

Comment: That's not what I suggested, and generally-speaking, you should never call `Tk()` more than once in a `tkinter` application (`pyautogui` probably automatically does it).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't find a way to move the prompt, so I did something easier. I just used IDLE.

```
import pyautogui

pyautogui.hotkey('alt','shift')
selected_picture = input()
pyautogui.hotkey('alt','shift')

if selected_picture == 1:
   pyautogui.click(500,270)
if selected_picture == 2:
    pyautogui.click(700,270)
if selected_picture == 3:
    pyautogui.click(900,270)
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if you want to change where the window appears or if you want to move it after it appears. If you just want to change the default window location, that can be done by importing `pymsgbox` and changing its `rootWindowPosition` value (the default value is `"+300+200"`) and then every message box you put after that will appear at the new location.

```
import pyautogui as pag
import pymsgbox

pag.prompt(text="300,200")  # appears at (300, 200)
pymsgbox.rootWindowPosition = "+500+500"
pag.prompt(text="500,500")  # appears at (500, 500)
```